# .Click action not doing anything - IE Simulation

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation, simulation

I'm trying to simulate the interaction with Google through the IE app and going through the DOM to get the classes I need and all is fine, stepping though the code, except the `.Click` action which doesn't cause a crash but it doesn't do anything (page doesn't navigate) - Code and screenshot of HTML below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test_Automation()
Dim ie, doc, eInput, eButton, eButtons As Object
Dim sURL, sTest As String

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
sURL = "https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=IpDvWK72LsjCaJCbjKAL&gws_rd=ssl"
sTest = "Test"

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate sURL
End With

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set doc = ie.document

Set eInput = doc.getElementByid("lst-ib")
Set eButtons = doc.getElementsByTagName("input")

eInput.Value = sTest

For Each eButton In eButtons
    If (eButton.getattribute("name") = "btnK") Then
        eButton.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Any advise on what I'm doing wrong would be great!

Comment: Maybe `eInputs.Value` should be `Inputs.Value`?

Comment: Your code has a few faults - not least `eInputs.Value = sTest` which throws an error because you have not defined `eInputs` anywhere. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then edit your question otherwise it is off-topic.

Comment: When debugging it really helps to use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules.

Comment: Apologies @Amorpheuses - I was cleaning up my code while copying it over to SE and messed it up again.. It's fixed now but the issue still remains - the `Click` action doesn't do anything

Comment: @RobinMackenzie code updated

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off just navigating to `https://www.google.co.uk/#q=test` ? Replace `test` with your search phrase and you will need to substitute spaces with `+`

Comment: @RobinMackenzie In the above example yes but the principal is what I want to figure out here - I want to log in to but inputting usernames and passwords and clicking the login button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of your `For...Next` loop at the bottom and replace it with this to click the button:

```
doc.forms(0).submit
```

The 0 can be changed to another number (such as 1 or 2) to click on a different button.  If there are multiple buttons on a page that can be clicked on it will just take some trial and error to find out which number matches the button you want to click.

Comment: You, sir, have earned yourself a best answer! Thank you!