# VBA [Internet Explorer] - Button Submit (Login)

Tags: vba, excel

I need some guidance on how I can press a button through VBA code. This had been done before using the code below: (See comment "<-----", to see what line that that I am stuck at.)

```
WWW = "http://sezv... ' I can't provide the address since it is on a server.

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate WWW              
StartDate & EndDate

Do
    If IE.READYSTATE = 4 Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop

With IE.Document
    .getElementById("Username").Value = "Test"  'Username 
    .getElementById("Password").Value = "Test2" 'Password
    .all("Logga in").Click                      ' <---------
End With
```

The HTML Looks like this:

`<input name="Logga in" class="button right" type="submit" value="Logga in"/>`

How would I go about doing it with a button that looks something like this?:

```
<button class="REGISTRATION_FORM-Button" style="border-top-color: currentColor; border-right-color: currentColor; border-bottom-color: currentColor; border-left-color: currentColor; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; background-image: url("http://sezvm1091:9090/ais/images/buttonBackground.gif"); background-attachment: scroll; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position-x: 0px; background-position-y: -50px; background-size: auto; background-origin: padding-box; background-clip: border-box; background-color: transparent;" type="button">
```

From what I know, this is probably connected to some Script, and if it is, can I get some guidance to how I can find it and implement it into the code above?
I would love to share the Script code, but it is 70207 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the button you could use e.g. `querySelector` where you can specify both the element name and class name.

```
Dim btn As HTMLButtonElement
Set btn = IE.document.querySelector("button[class=REGISTRATION_FORM-Button]")
btn.Click
```

In case there are more butons with same class like this:

```
<button title="Klarmarkera (ctrl+K)" class="ACTION_BUTTON-Button" style="border-top-color" type="button" >Klarmarkera (ctrl+K)</button>
<button title="Nytt samtal (ctrl+S)" class="ACTION_BUTTON-Button" style="border-top-color" type="button" >Nytt samtal (ctrl+S)</button>
```

then more attributes can be used in `querySelector` e.g. `title`:

```
Set btn = IE.document.querySelector("button[class=ACTION_BUTTON-Button][title='Nytt samtal (ctrl+S)']")
```

In case when more class names are present like here:

```
<button class="FancyButton FancyButton-ACTION_FORM-Button" style="border-top-color" type="button">Fancy Form Button</button>
```

the `querySelector` could look like this:

```
Set btn = IE.document.querySelector("button[class='FancyButton FancyButton-ACTION_FORM-Button']")
```

Comment: Holy, it worked... So simple... So awesome! Thank you so incredible much!

Comment: Dee, I have a related problem to the the question above.

I have found two buttons with the same class so when I run the code nothing happens:

`<button title="Klarmarkera (ctrl+K)" class="ACTION_BUTTON-Button"`
and
`<button title="Nytt samtal (ctrl+S)" class="ACTION_BUTTON-Button"`

**I have another button that gives me a Run-time error '-2147352319 (80020101)': Method 'querySelector' of object 'JScriptTypeInfo' failed**
`<button class="FancyButton FancyButton-ACTION_FORM-Button"`

Comment: Flawless, it all works!

I managed to figure out how to do the same with a label:
`Dim Lbl As HTMLInputElement  
Set aaa = ie.Document.querySelector("input[class=ACTION_FORM-AIMWebGUIActionFormVoiceDial-TextBox]")  
aaa.Value = "91768"`

Answer (score 2):

I asked nearly the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397401/click-action-not-doing-anything-ie-simulation/43403200#43403200) a couple of weeks ago and the solution (which worked) was to use `forms().submit` so for your code above, it'd be

```
With IE.Document
    .getElementById("Username").Value = "Test"  'Username 
    .getElementById("Password").Value = "Test2" 'Password
    .forms(0).submit ' the index is currently set to 0 but this can be updated as per the DOM
End With
```

Comment: yes this should work the same way! So you don't actually need to find the button, but just find the form and submit it.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, it doesn't work in my case. I get Run-time error '424': Object required. I have tried various ways, but unfortunately it didn't work... I'll give you an up-vote though. I tried your code and it works, but it doesn't work on the site that I am using. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should help you . . .

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html